# Dynamic Reporting options for Java EE based application

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, report

I have reviewed several popular open source solutions for Java based reporting tool. i.e Pentaho, BIRT etc. as I have moderately large dynamic reporting requirements in my struts-spring based web application.

earlier I have used embedded pentaho reporting Engine in my web application for static reports. but we have faced performance and memory issues.

I would like to build my reporting solutions similar to site : http://www.mint.com. These reports are very intuitive and interactive. my main criteria are.

- easy integration with existing web application and reports should be accessible from with in my application
- reports should be displayed in Jsp/html pages without any viewer tool.
- performance and memory consumption are key criteria. report loading time as well as dynamic report interactivity should be quick.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [m-Power](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/solutions/reporting.html).  It's Java-based, can handle large reporting requirements, and integrates well with other applications.  It's also very customizable, so you can adjust it to generate reports that fit your desired look and feel. Here's an example of an [interactive report](http://crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.R00090s) created with m-Power.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I briefly over viewed it and it looks good so far. I am trying to understand more about integration process and overall features of m-Power. its look like it is code generation tool.

Comment: we have found another good tool LogiXML. it seems to fulfill most of our requirements. I am currently evaluating it.

Comment: @pdhinoja - To answer your first question -- m-Power is more than a simple report builder, but reporting is one of its strong points.  Also, I don't know if you checked out the [technical specs](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/products/specs.html), but it sounds like m-Power creates applications that use the same foundation as you currently use.